# HTML one div affects another div, but I only want to target the one

Tags: html, css

So basically I want a side bar and a navigation bar. But when I set the div2 (the side bar) top margin to 110px it moves div1 down with it. Please help me.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="div1">
            <div id="div2"> 

            </div>
        </div>

    </body>


</html>
```

And the CSS...

```
body {
    background-color:#CCC;
}

#div1 {
    width:auto;
    height:100px;
    background-color:gray;
    border-radius:10px;
}

#div2 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top:110px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shane__kerr/5p8Qr/2/

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/5p8Qr/5/

Comment: try `margin-top:-110px` for `div1`.

Comment: @Sergio has it right -- does div1 need to be inside div2 for some reason?

Comment: @Sergio TS probably wants one div to be inside the other.

Comment: you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5p8Qr/13/

Comment: @Sergio Thanks, I think this will work for me.

Comment: @Shane, ok! I posted it as a answer also.

Answer (score 0):

Change the height in `#div1` to `auto` and set `margin-top:100px` in `#div1`, not `#div2`.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6SWt/)

Now i did a `float:left` and `width:100%` to div1 and `clear:both` to div2.

Dont forget to add `clear:both` to any div inside the div1

Answer (score 0):

When you add a margin-top to div2, the webpage also creates the other elements to 'trap' that element on its position. To fix this you should use `display: inline-block;` this way all not given margin is gone.

*Why not use float?*

 Well basically float also sets the display to inline-block but will also position the element. With display-inline only the given margin will be used, without reposition it.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5p8Qr/15/)**

Comment: `float != inline block` and inline block does preserve whitespace characters, where float doesn't http://jsfiddle.net/5p8Qr/18/

Answer (score 0):

I thinks your CSS looks good. But I think div 1 and 2 should not be inside each other to achieve what you want.

Try this:

```
<body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xzdac/)